# Empty body sending list of files

Tags: angular, post, angular8

I'm trying to send a list of files to my server in Laravel with angular 8, but when I send it with a post request, the payload body, it's empty and I think it has to be with the content type.

service:

```
createImageAssigment(images, apartment, building) {
    const img = Array.from(images);
    return this.http.post(this.baseurl + `/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx`, img );
}
```

That img var contains a list like this:

`FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, 3: File, length: 4}`

**proto**: FileList

When I send it, it shows the following:
Request payload:

```
[{},{},{},{}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they should be included in a FormData

```
    createImageAssigment(images, apartment, building) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        const img = Array.from(images);
        var myFormData = new FormData();
        myFormData.append('image', img);
        return this.http.post(this.baseurl + `/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx`, myFormData,{
  headers: headers
} );
    }
```

Comment: it still sends an empty form :(

Comment: I just updated my answer, try to add headers to the API call